# How to set the table view height.when search bar is appear and disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have one table view and I am displaying some data from api. And I have aded one search bar.And also I have one button name called "search bar button item button ".

So what the condition is , when screen load - my search bar will be in hide.And if i press that " search bar button " then only search bar will be show .

Here is that code:

```
@IBAction func searchPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if searchBar.hidden
    {
        searchBar.hidden = false
    }
    else
    {
        searchBar.hidden = true
    }
}
```

What I need is while the first time search bar is hidden I can see more space on above of my table view. But when my search bar is in show. No space are seeing in my table view.

But when my search bar is in hidden. I am seeing more space on above my table view. How to fix that?

Here is the image when search bar is hidden and space on above table view :

[image: No search bar]

Here is the image when search bar is shown :

[image: Search bar]

Now how can I fix this problem. What I need is when my search bar is hidden the space should not be shown and my table view should fill that space.

How to do that? I tried this :

```
if searchBar.hidden
{
    searchBar.hidden = false
    TableViewList.rowHeight = 469
}
else
{
    searchBar.hidden = true
    TableViewList.rowHeight = 425
}
```

**Updated code :**

```
@IBAction func searchPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if searchBar.hidden
    {
        searchBar.hidden = false
        TableViewList.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)
    }
    else
    {
        searchBar.hidden = true
        TableViewList.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-searchBar.frame.size.height)
    }  
}
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Pin your `UITableView` to the bottom of your `UISearchBar`. When displaying the `UISearchBar`, adjust the `constant` of it's top constraint to be `0`. When it's hidden, adjust the `constant` of it's top constraint to be `-searchBar.bounds.height`. These values assume that the `UISearchBar` is pinned to the bottom of the `UINavigationBar`

Comment: can you please suggest with some example code.I am new to ios

Answer (score 0):

No need for extra code for this, just remove your search bar from table view and place in the top of your table view. and adjust the table view height if search bar hidden 
{
TableViewList.frame = CGRectmake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)
}

else
{
TableViewList.frame = CGRectmake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-srachbar.frame.size.height)
}

Comment: i applied your code.But in that else part .I mean in that -searchbar.Its not taking the value.So i did - 44.But i am getting error ` Value of type 'Int' has no member 'frame'`

Comment: i tried to Change but if i give - serch bar, its going end point to my screen ( m table view)

Comment: din get you.how to do that statically

Comment: searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40 or 50 or 60, height: 50)

Comment: please change the y position.

Comment: i tried with - 44,-22,-0..I tried all these value.But still my saerch bar is showing in very upper part of screen

Comment: why your are taking (-) sign values, Some where your code is updating the frame, please check once if any where you forgot the comment the code. probably my code should work. try the following finally, keep do change the y position. up to your requirement. //                                                            searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50)